Reassemble BTRFS RAID1 array (was created by mkfs.btrfs)
I've got RAID1 array (4 HDD) from old dead system. Need to reassemble that RAID1 array on a new system.
Old and dead linux system was installed to one separate HDD (which is unrecoverable dead) and that RAID1-array was used as mounted data storage. So I've seen that as one big ~9Tb storage.
Never done that before and very important to save data on that HDD array. So it is not time to experiments, and I'm afraid to damage data.
How to safely reassemble that RAID1 array on new system?

Some information
[>] RAID1 was created by command on the old system:
mkfs.btrfs -f -L data -m raid1 -d raid1 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc/ dev/sdd

Here are 2 HDD pairs that is assembled to one big virtual disk.
Then it was mounted in /etc/fstab with options 'defaults,compress=zlib'
[>] RAID1 disk array is labeled as 'data' on new system:
nas@nas:~$ sudo lsblk  -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME        FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT                    LABEL
loop0                104M /snap/core/16928              
loop1               55.7M /snap/core18/2823             
loop2               10.1M /snap/canonical-livepatch/278 
loop3               63.9M /snap/core20/2264             
loop4               74.2M /snap/core22/1380             
loop5              130.1M /snap/docker/2915             
loop6              161.9M /snap/microk8s/6641           
loop7              307.5M /snap/nextcloud/41512         
loop8               38.7M /snap/snapd/21465             
loop9              160.1M /snap/wekan/1999              
sda         btrfs    3.6T                               data
sdb         btrfs    3.6T                               data
sdc         btrfs    5.5T                               data
sdd         btrfs    5.5T                               data
nvme0n1            953.9G                               
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat       1G /boot/efi                     
├─nvme0n1p2 btrfs  918.8G /                             
└─nvme0n1p3 swap      34G [SWAP] 

[>] btrfs device scan --all devices shows
nas@nas:~$ sudo btrfs device scan --all devices
Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
registered: /dev/nvme0n1p2
registered: /dev/sdd
registered: /dev/sdb
registered: /dev/sdc
registered: /dev/sda

[>] btrfs filesystem show
nas@nas:~$ sudo btrfs filesystem show
[sudo] password for nas: 
Label: none  uuid: 6e9ee039-99fb-4dc8-9d44-97df210810b2
    Total devices 1 FS bytes used 4.99GiB
    devid    1 size 918.82GiB used 9.02GiB path /dev/nvme0n1p2

Label: 'data'  uuid: 360881c9-1502-46c5-8e03-099dd64049ad
    Total devices 4 FS bytes used 1.61TiB
    devid    1 size 5.46TiB used 1.62TiB path /dev/sdd
    devid    2 size 5.46TiB used 1.62TiB path /dev/sdc
    devid    3 size 3.64TiB used 1.01GiB path /dev/sdb
    devid    4 size 3.64TiB used 1.01GiB path /dev/sda


The problem was solved!
Just mount the disk with the same params as old was mounted.
Unfortunately, a person who has placed a hint removed his post. Thank you very much!
I've done the followed:
1.. Take disk array UUID from:
nas@nas:~$ sudo btrfs filesystem show
[sudo] password for nas: 
Label: none  uuid: 6e9ee039-99fb-4dc8-9d44-97df210810b2
    Total devices 1 FS bytes used 4.99GiB
    devid    1 size 918.82GiB used 9.02GiB path /dev/nvme0n1p2

Label: 'data'  uuid: 360881c9-1502-46c5-8e03-099dd64049ad
    Total devices 4 FS bytes used 1.61TiB
    devid    1 size 5.46TiB used 1.62TiB path /dev/sdd
    devid    2 size 5.46TiB used 1.62TiB path /dev/sdc
    devid    3 size 3.64TiB used 1.01GiB path /dev/sdb
    devid    4 size 3.64TiB used 1.01GiB path /dev/sda

2.. Find this one in /dev/disk/by-uuid/ (Ubuntu Server 24.04)
nas@nas:/dev/disk/by-uuid$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 120 Apr 30 06:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 200 Apr 30 06:45 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   9 Apr 30 06:45 360881c9-1502-46c5-8e03-099dd64049ad -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root  15 Apr 30 06:45 6e9ee039-99fb-4dc8-9d44-97df210810b2 -> ../../nvme0n1p2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root  15 Apr 30 06:45 716dbd38-03d8-449d-aa9e-c1237a7f2476 -> ../../nvme0n1p3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root  15 Apr 30 06:45 B4B1-D70A -> ../../nvme0n1p1

3.. Mount this one in /etc/fstab file to /store
A line to fstab was added:
/dev/disk/by-uuid/360881c9-1502-46c5-8e03-099dd64049ad /store btrfs defaults,compress=zlib 0 0

(!!!) this line is relevant for Ubuntu Server 24.04, for old Debian linux system it was slightly different.
One more time thank you very much!

Ya, it's really that easy. PS I recommend using labels for BTRFS filesystem, so you can mount it by using the label, which is easier to do, especially on CLI

PPS you should migrate the data to new drives too
